# "name constraints check failed" on certificate

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore

I have a certificate for my server that has been generated using the company's CA.
Everything works fine in my browser (my company installed the needed CA certificates I presume) and if I call

```
openssl s_client -CAfile CertificateChain.txt -showcerts -connect myserver.company.com:443
```

I get a "OK" answer.
But in java, even after I imported the relevant certificate chain (but not the server certificate), I get a:

```
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: name constraints check failed
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.ConstraintsChecker.verifyNameConstraints(ConstraintsChecker.java:154)
```

I'm confident the intermediate certificates have been installed properly in the keystore; if I remove one of them I get different errors.

What is a "name constraints check failed"? I can't find much with google...

Comment: NameConstraints is an optional (and rare) X.509/PKIX extension [described here](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.10) that where used can limit the scope of certs issued by a CA; this might make sense for a 'company' CA especially if it chains to a public CA under CABforum ruies as a 'technically constrained subordinate CA'. By 'OK answer' do you actually mean 'Verify return code: 0 (ok)' or something else? I'd be surprised if OpenSSL and Java differ here, but you (or rather the CA) might have done something unusual or unclear that triggered a bug in (at least!) one.

Comment: PS: this probably _won't_ be a programming problem or issue, and might fit better on security.SX.